# How to define or pass auth guard for broadcast authentication routes instead of default auth guard?

Tags: laravel, socket.io, laravel-5.4, laravel-authorization, laravel-echo

I am very new to realtime event broadcasting, I have simple laravel-echo-server setup and working with everything. I am unable to set/define authentication against other auth `guard` it is always checking with `user/default` `guard` defined in `auth.php`
I have setup the authentication routes for each guards private channels in `routes/channel.php` as below per documentation.

> For auth guard user private channels

```
Broadcast::channel('users.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
   Log::info(class_basename($user));
   return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

> For auth guard admin private channels

```
Broadcast::channel('admins.{id}', function ($admin, $id) {
   Log::info(class_basename($admin));
   return (int) $admin->id === (int) $id;
});
```

It works fine for guard `user` that is the first case but never worked for the second one i.e. `admin` guard.
and the

`Log::info(class_basename($admin))` always returns `User` class.

So, how do we pass or define that it should use `admin` guard instead of `user`.
after exploring the inside of `Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\Broadcaster` I found out that below in line `411`

```
public function user($guard = null)
{
    return call_user_func($this->getUserResolver(), $guard);
}
```

So, if we can pass this guard parameter it can solve the purpose.
If anyone can give me anything or way of authorising with multiple guard setup that will be very helpfull.
Using `Laravel 5.4, laravel-echo-server, Redis, Socket.IO`

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this to work with 2 separate login screens and 2 separate users and customers tables.

Firstly I followed the Laracasts video on private channel broadcasting. The video says to put all the echo event listeners in your bootstrap.js. This will work with one users table. However for 2 separate tables users, customers you need to place the relevant echo event listeners in your 2 separate app.blade.php layouts files. For users in one and for customers in the other. However the listeners should be positioned at the bottom.

```
window.Echo.private('App.User.' +     window.Laravel.user.id) .listen('Event', e => { etc. });

window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([ 'customer' => auth()->guard('customer')->user() ]) !!};

window.Echo.private('App.Customer.' + window.Laravel.customer.id) .listen('Event', e => { etc. });
```

Then in your routes/channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id)
return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('App.Customer.{id}', function ($user, $id)
return (int) auth()->guard('customer')->user()->id === (int) $id;
}); // Note I do not compare "$user" here
```

Then in BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'web', 'auth:customer']);
require base_path('routes/channels.php');

//Remove Broadcast::routes();
```

A customer can receive a private message and so can a user. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in the otherwhere, simply use `Request` [facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades) in the closure.

In your case:

```
Broadcast::channel('admins.{id}', function ($user, int $id) {
   return Request::user('admin')->id === $id;
});
```

The arguments sent to the closure can not be change by user, it is controlled by laravel framework.
(see `BroadcastManage` and `RedisBroadcaster`, or other implementations of `Illumiante\Contracts\Broadcasting\Broadcaster`)