# Laravel echo admin channel authentication error

Tags: laravel, echo

I'am using Laravel 5.5 with echo for an admin panel  ,
the main guard (web) is related to Admin class ,
the private channel name that i want to get is Admin.1 ,

The problem is when i change the channel name from

```
 Echo.private('App.User.' + this.userid)
```

to

```
Echo.private('App.Admin.' + this.userid)
```

it gets me this error

> broadcasting/auth 500 (Internal Server Error)

what i tried is :
i put this

```
 Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => [ 'api', 'web','auth' ] ]);
```

in web.php and api.php and BroadcastServiceProvider.php put it doesn't seem to work
i also tried this soltion
[How to define or pass auth guard for broadcast authentication routes instead of default auth guard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682681/how-to-define-or-pass-auth-guard-for-broadcast-authentication-routes-instead-of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by :
adding this to BroadcastServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes();

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');

     /*
     * for auth user channel
     */
      Broadcast::channel('App.Admin.{id}',function($user, $id){
          return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your echo settings set **authEndpoint** to 'broadcasting/auth'.
here's the code that works for me after facing the same problem.

```
new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '{{env("PUSHER_APP_KEY")}}',
    cluster: 'us2',
    encrypted: true,
    authEndpoint: '{!! env("APP_URL") !!}/broadcasting/auth',
});
```

Comment: @MohamedZayed Yep, adding only this line along with `Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => [ 'web','auth' ] ]);` did it for me.

Comment: though, make sure you are not forgetting to add `{!! env("APP_URL") !!}' and re-check your APP_URL and Pusher configurations if you are using pusher.

Comment: instead of  APP_URL i hard coded the  path and it didn't work